# Scrapy Request giving 400 error while Python requests giving 200

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I have the following Python script working:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.galaxus.ch/api/graphql/enter-search"

payload = json.dumps([
  {
    "operationName": "ENTER_SEARCH",
    "variables": {
      "limit": 24,
      "offset": 0,
      "query": "8719934001237",
      "filters": [],
      "sortOrder": None,
      "include": [
        "bra",
        "pt",
        "pr",
        "off"
      ],
      "searchQueryId": "5ca2074a-59ea-44be-a6b4-74946d50285c",
      "siteId": None
    },
    "query": "query ENTER_SEARCH($query: String!, $sortOrder: ProductSort, $limit: Int = 9, $offset: Int = 0, $filters: [SearchFilter], $include: [String!], $exclude: [String!], $searchQueryId: String, $rewriters: [String!], $siteId: String) {\n  search(\n    query: $query\n    filters: $filters\n    searchQueryId: $searchQueryId\n    rewriters: $rewriters\n    siteId: $siteId\n  ) {\n    products(limit: $limit, offset: $offset, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {\n      total\n      hasMore\n      nextOffset\n      results {\n        ...ProductSearchResult\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    filters(include: $include, exclude: $exclude) {\n      product {\n        identifier\n        name\n        filterType\n        score\n        tooltip {\n          ...FilterTooltipResult\n          __typename\n        }\n        ...CheckboxSearchFilterResult\n        ...RangeSearchFilterResult\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    magazinePages(limit: 3) {\n      ids {\n        id\n        score\n        __typename\n      }\n      total\n      __typename\n    }\n    authors(limit: 3) {\n      ids {\n        id\n        score\n        __typename\n      }\n      total\n      __typename\n    }\n    discussions(limit: 3) {\n      ids {\n        id\n        score\n        __typename\n      }\n      total\n      __typename\n    }\n    questions(limit: 3) {\n      ids {\n        id\n        score\n        __typename\n      }\n      total\n      __typename\n    }\n    ratings(limit: 3) {\n      ids {\n        id\n        score\n        __typename\n      }\n      total\n      __typename\n    }\n    productTypes(limit: 24) {\n      total\n      results {\n        id\n        name\n        primarySynonyms\n        isVisible\n        description\n        metaDescription\n        imageUrl\n        searchScore\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    brands(limit: 24) {\n      total\n      results {\n        id\n        title\n        searchScore\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    _meta {\n      queryInfo {\n        correctedQuery\n        didYouMeanQuery\n        lastProductSearchPass\n        executedSearchTerm\n        testGroup\n        isManagedQuery\n        isRerankedQuery\n        __typename\n      }\n      redirectionUrl\n      portalReferral {\n        productCount\n        portalName\n        url\n        productImageUrls\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment ProductSearchResult on ProductSearchResultItem {\n  searchScore\n  mandatorSpecificData {\n    ...ProductMandatorSpecific\n    __typename\n  }\n  product {\n    ...ProductMandatorIndependent\n    __typename\n  }\n  offer {\n    ...ProductOffer\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment FilterTooltipResult on FilterTooltip {\n  text\n  moreInformationLink\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment CheckboxSearchFilterResult on CheckboxSearchFilter {\n  options {\n    identifier\n    name\n    productCount\n    score\n    referenceValue {\n      value\n      unit {\n        abbreviation\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    preferredValue {\n      value\n      unit {\n        abbreviation\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    tooltip {\n      ...FilterTooltipResult\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment RangeSearchFilterResult on RangeSearchFilter {\n  referenceMin\n  preferredMin\n  referenceMax\n  preferredMax\n  referenceStepSize\n  preferredStepSize\n  rangeMergeInfo {\n    isBottomMerged\n    isTopMerged\n    __typename\n  }\n  referenceUnit {\n    abbreviation\n    __typename\n  }\n  preferredUnit {\n    abbreviation\n    __typename\n  }\n  rangeFilterDataPoint {\n    ...RangeFilterDataPointResult\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductMandatorSpecific on MandatorSpecificData {\n  isBestseller\n  isDeleted\n  showroomSites\n  sectorIds\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductMandatorIndependent on ProductV2 {\n  id\n  productId\n  name\n  nameProperties\n  productTypeId\n  productTypeName\n  brandId\n  brandName\n  averageRating\n  totalRatings\n  totalQuestions\n  isProductSet\n  images {\n    url\n    height\n    width\n    __typename\n  }\n  energyEfficiency {\n    energyEfficiencyColorType\n    energyEfficiencyLabelText\n    energyEfficiencyLabelSigns\n    energyEfficiencyImage {\n      url\n      height\n      width\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  seo {\n    seoProductTypeName\n    seoNameProperties\n    productGroups {\n      productGroup1\n      productGroup2\n      productGroup3\n      productGroup4\n      __typename\n    }\n    gtin\n    __typename\n  }\n  hasVariants\n  smallDimensions\n  basePrice {\n    priceFactor\n    value\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ProductOffer on OfferV2 {\n  id\n  productId\n  offerId\n  shopOfferId\n  price {\n    amountIncl\n    amountExcl\n    currency\n    fraction\n    __typename\n  }\n  deliveryOptions {\n    mail {\n      classification\n      futureReleaseDate\n      __typename\n    }\n    pickup {\n      siteId\n      classification\n      futureReleaseDate\n      __typename\n    }\n    detailsProvider {\n      productId\n      offerId\n      quantity\n      type\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  label\n  type\n  volumeDiscountPrices {\n    minAmount\n    price {\n      amountIncl\n      amountExcl\n      currency\n      __typename\n    }\n    isDefault\n    __typename\n  }\n  salesInformation {\n    numberOfItems\n    numberOfItemsSold\n    isEndingSoon\n    validFrom\n    __typename\n  }\n  incentiveText\n  isIncentiveCashback\n  isNew\n  isSalesPromotion\n  hideInProductDiscovery\n  canAddToBasket\n  hidePrice\n  insteadOfPrice {\n    type\n    price {\n      amountIncl\n      amountExcl\n      currency\n      fraction\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  minOrderQuantity\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment RangeFilterDataPointResult on RangeFilterDataPoint {\n  count\n  referenceValue {\n    value\n    unit {\n      abbreviation\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  preferredValue {\n    value\n    unit {\n      abbreviation\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n"
  }
])
headers = {
  'accept-language': 'de-CH',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

However, when I convert it to scrapy request, just changing the "data" parameter by "body" I get 400 error. I have seen possible solutions at stack overflow but none seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, when making an scrapy request is needed to eliminate the "[]" at the beginning and end of the body